# Terminology. Can I say that $t^2 - 9$ is factorable by a "product of conjugates"?

Tags: terminology, factoring

Can I say that $t^2 - 9$ is factorable by $(t -3)(t + 3)$, a "product of conjugates"?  Is that correct terminology?  It seems so ingrained in mathematical culture that in all of Wikipedia's [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation), there's only qualified conjugates such as "complex conjugate", but they all seem to conform what I'm inclined to say.

Comment: I think not. We can say that the roots of an *irreducible* polynomial are (algebraic) conjugates, but I think it's misleading to use the term here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to whether or not terminology is appropriate is very often; *depends*. If I had to give a direct answer, I would say no. Here is my reasoning.

In number theory, your terminology at least has a slight foothold. The reason is that in general, $t^2-n = (t-\sqrt{n})(t+\sqrt{n})$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, and the operation $a+b\sqrt{n}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{n}$, e.g. for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$, is usually called conjugation. It can be viewed as a generalization of complex conjugation for Gaussian integers. The problem is, for this to be a well-defined function, we need that $n$ is not a perfect square, which $9$ is. So in spirit, I can accept seeing this a form of conjugation, but in reality, it is not.

If you were factoring this polynomial while doing complex analysis, or indeed any setting outside the world of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$, I would stay away from this terminology, in fear of confusion with complex conjugation and the like.

You could define a new form of conjugation for polynomials, $(a_nt^n+\dots+a_1t+a_0)\mapsto (a_nt^n+\dots+a_1t-a_0)$. But in its essence, terminology is about communication, and if it's a terminology that might confuse people, it is bad terminology.

Comment: Wow.  There's a lot of depth that I had no idea.  Can you elaborate on why $n$ needs to be a perfect square?  I don't see the problem.  Why would the function be ill-defined?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})=\lbrace a+b\sqrt{n} \mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\rbrace$. This is well defined for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now, we want to define the operation $a+b\sqrt{n}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{n}$. But we get a problem if $n$ is a perfect square, since then $\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Indeed, let $n=9$. Then we see that we have both $11 = 11+0\cdot \sqrt{9}$ and $11 = 2+3\cdot \sqrt{9}$. Thus applying our  "operation", we would get both $11\mapsto 11$ and $11\mapsto 2-3\cdot 3 = -7$. Therefore, our operation is not well defined.

Comment: The idea is that only for $n$ *not* a perfect square do you have a UNIQUE presentation of an element $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ as $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Got ya!  That's a very cool terminology to discuss then.  You convinced me.  I will not call it a product of conjugates then and I almost didn't ask the question thinking it was too basic and thinking that the term was clearly correctly used.  The moral I guess is that we really should always check everything, even when it's just a term.  There's always more depth to nearly everything.  Thank you!